# What are Arguments in Python Class Inheritance used for?

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance

When browsing the source code for the django_filters library, I found a class declaration syntax that I've never seen before: inheritance with arguments. I could not find an explanation in the official python class [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Here is the [source](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/e6d5f2dd0f9e62dea7e7ac5bd933187bcd2e1913/django_filters/filterset.py#L452), snippet below:

```
class FilterSet(BaseFilterSet, metaclass=FilterSetMetaclass):
    pass
```

what does **metaclass=FilterSetMetaclass** in the class definition do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two uses for keyword arguments in the list of base classes.

1. The `metaclass` argument is used specially to indicate which metaclass (instead of `type`) to use to create the class. (In Python 2, this was done by assigning a value to the class attribute `__metaclass__` in the body of the `class` statement.)

   A `class` statement is essentially a call to the metaclass.

   ```
   class Foo(metaclass=Bar):
       pass
   ```

   is equivalent to `Foo = Bar('Foo', (), {})`. The default metaclass is `type`, that is

   ```
   class Foo():
       pass
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   class Foo(metaclass=type):
       pass
   ```
2. Other keyword arguments are passed along to `__init_subclass__`.

Both of the above are simplifications; see [Customizing Class creation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) for more details.